# Changing language without changing locale in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, localization, translation

I currently have a JSF application which sets the locale based on a user's choice of language. He gets a dropdown, and when choosing English, I set the locale to en, etc.
This works very nice with number formats as well as with the language strings loaded from my ResourceBundle.

So for en, I get English words and a . as decimal seperator.
For fr, I get French and a , as decimal seperator.

However, there is now a requirement that for this website, the number format must always have a , as decimal seperator. So, I was thinking to keep the locale fixed to fr.

Still the user must be able to change his language.
So, is it possible in JSF to load a different language without changing the locale?

Answer (score 2):

Seams you need a special solution for formatting, so overwriting the formatters might be the better solution. I think JSF supports replacing the default number format.

Comment: Indeed! Seems I need some vacation as I'm starting to think out overly complicated solutions ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just explicitly specify the `locale` attribute of the `<f:convertNumber>` tags which you're using there.

E.g.

```html
<f:convertNumber ... locale="fr" />
```

or something like

```html
<f:convertNumber ... locale="#{app.defaultNumberLocale}" />
```

It would otherwise indeed default to [`UIViewRoot#getLocale()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getLocale%28%29), as you're experiencing.

#### See also:

- [`<f:convertNumber>` tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/convertNumber.html) - read the `locale` attribute

Comment: Indeed I came this far. Reading the docs though, I think your `locale="fr_FR"`is not going to work, as the first arg to `Locale(String)` has to be a lowercase two-letter ISO-639 code